# Equivalence between Intermediate value property and connectedness of $f([a,b])$ for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, connectedness

From what I understand, for a continuous real-valued function defined on $[a,b]$, $f([a,b])$ is connected if and only if $f$ has the intermediate value property.

There is one side of this equivalence ($\implies$) that is well explained in my book, and easy.

However, the other side $(\impliedby$) is less easy for me.

If $f$ has the IVP then $\forall \lambda$ such as $f(a) <\lambda < f(b)$ we have that $\lambda \in f([a,b])$.

$f(a) \in f([a,b])$ and $f(b)\in f([a,b])$ but for me there are only two ways of showing that a set $I$ (whose endpoints are $e_1$ and $e_2$) is connected:

- either by saying that $\forall z$ between $e_1$ and $e_2$, $z$ belongs to $I$
- either by moving along $x$ and $y$ all over $I$, with $x<y$ and showing that $x<z<y\implies z\in I$

Here it is clear that the first method can't apply (since $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ ***are not*** endpoints  of $f([a,b])$) and the second method seems to be a bit difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not necessarily limited to $f(a)<\lambda<f(b)$, because it’s not necessarily the case that $f$ is monotonic increasing. Really, saying ‘$f$ has the IVP’ is the same as saying: ‘$f([a,b])$ is a (degenerate) interval’.

And it is a well known fact that (degenerate) intervals are the only connected subspaces of $\Bbb R$.

I’m not really sure what you’re doing in your own attempt, to be honest. Connectivity has a precise topological definition and in $\Bbb R$ we are lucky that it simplifies to the property of being an interval, and you seem to be trying to show an interval is interval.

Comment: Ok, so the intermediate value property is not just for $\lambda$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ but instead has a wider scope ?

Comment: @niobium The IVP is just: if $x,y\in[a,b]$ and $f(x)<c<f(y)$ then there is $z$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(z)=c$. Now, it would be reasonable to define it slightly differently by further specifying that $z$ is between $x$ and $y$. In that case, you'd actually need: "$f$ maps connected sets to connected sets" to seal the deal